# Scala - how to filter Seq base on Future

Tags: scala, future

I have a simple method which should filter all persons if they have any event. So if `Person` do not have any event he should be removed from list. Filtered list is returned in the end.

```
 def filterPersonsWithEvents(persons: Seq[Person]): Seq[Person] = {
    persons.filter(sport => {         
      eventRepo.find(person.name) != null
    })
    persons
  }
```

The problem is method `find` from `eventRepo` return Future[Event]. And this method do not filter `persons` in good way. How should I change it to get correct results? I am new in Scala so maybe I do not know some "tricks"

**EDITED**

Now my code looks like:

```
 def filterPersonsWithEvents(persons: Seq[Person]): Seq[Person] = {
         Future.traverse(persons)(person => {      
      eventRepo.find(person.name).map(e => person-> e)
    }).map(_.filter(_._2 != null).map(_._1))
      }
```

Comment: if you have a method that returns a `Future[...]`, it's quite unlikely that will ever return a `null`. Is that really how that method works or does it return a `Future[Option[Event]]` instead??

Comment: I would assume `eventRepo.find` returns `Future[Event]` which will indeed never return `null` but the contained `Event` could be `null`. hence my recommendation to use `traverse` in conjunction with an afterward applied `filter. I should probably flesh this out in my answer

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez - no, it only return Future[Event] without Option.

Answer (score 1):

once more the solution is [`traverse`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#traverse[A,B,M[X]%3C:TraversableOnce[X]](in:M[A])(fn:A=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[B])(implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[M[A],B,M[B]],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[M[B]]). traverse let's you take `List[X]` and `X => Future[Y]` and gives you `Future[List[Y]]` so it "flips" the containing types. then you can just `map` over the outer `Future` and `filter` the inner `List`.

EDIT: Added doc link for `traverse` the typesignature is a tad scary though.

EDIT 2: to make this answer complete. Here a full example https://scalafiddle.io/sf/p84FSFv/0

Comment: Thanks. Could you give an example because I think I do not understand well

Comment: http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-9-beginner-tutorial-using-scala-futures/#future-sequence this seems to have an ok explanation. `sequence` is a special case of `traverse` but both have sections in there

Comment: Your example return `Future[List[Person]] ` but I would like to return `Seq[Person]` only

Comment: you could block on the future but that might have drawbacks. basically you'd force your async api you have (through `eventRepo.find`) back to sync. you can do this with `Await.result(fut, Duration.inf)` this might block infinitely long though. I would recommend not doing this in the function itself but rather at the latest possible boundary. Also this will throw exception if the future fails IIRC

Comment: Hi, I used your tips but persons are not filtered correctly. I get same result as I pass to method before filtering.

Comment: Are you filtering for `null` can you share the exact code maybe?

Comment: does your eventRepo actually return `null` in the Future? it does work in the scala fiddle

Comment: This eventRepo return 0 if there is no event for a person.But this Future.traverse return new list with persons who has one event at least?

Comment: I cannot understand what `.map(e => person-> e)` should return

Comment: `.map(e => person-> e)` just makes a tuple `(Person, Event)` because in the end we want the `Person` back. this means we'll have a `Future[List[(Person, Event)]]` then we filter the inner list to only contain entries where `Event` is not `null` and finally we `map` again to ignore the `Event`. What do you mean by "return 0" ?

Comment: `e` returns some object wich has few fields. Base on one of this fields - `List`, I decide what to return. If this `list` is empty then person do not have events, otherwise have. So, in your code `e` is probably the "main" object, but I want to get "inside" values.

Comment: Do you know how to replace this mappings with foldLeft/fold or foldRight functions to improve performance?

Comment: sorry that I get back to you so late . to address your first comment: if it's not a `null` issue you just have to adjust the `filter` appropriatly. As for your question about `foldLeft` vs `foldRight`. that's the reason I personally never use `Seq` it gives you no information as to runtime cost of operations. it depends on the underlying collection